# not getting result from whenever gem (0.9.7) in rails 2.3.5 through localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

```
 #my rake task

    namespace :send_digest_email do
     desc "send digest email" 
     task :send_digest_email => :environment do             
        @sender="govind.shawas20@gmail.com"             
        recipient= "govind.mietcse@gmail.com" # recieprnt
        @school = School.all
            @school.each do |s|
            MultiSchool.current_school = School.find s.id
            # to send mail  
           FedenaEmailer::deliver_send_custom_mail(@sender,recipient)                                             
        end 
     end
  end
```

## My schedule.rb file

```
   every 2.minutes do
     rake 'send_digest_email:send_digest_email',
    :environment => 'development'
  end

   every :reboot do 
     rake 'send_digest_email:send_digest_email',
     :environment => 'development'
   end
```

#run command to start job .the commands are

```
  1. whenever --update-crontab store

     [write] crontab file updated

  2. crontab -l

   # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: store @reboot /bin/bash -l -c     'cd /home/rank/gvs/new_rank/vendor/plugins/rank_gvs_customization &&
   RAILS_ENV=development rake send_digest_email:send_digest_email
   --silent'       
   0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58
   * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rank/gvs/new_rank/vendor/plugins/rank_gvs_customization &&
   RAILS_ENV=development rake send_digest_email:send_digest_email
   --silent'
```

# End Whenever generated tasks for: store

## I run to check cron is running or not?

```
   1.service cron status
   cron start/running, process 924
```

## But i am not getting any mail through cron.

when i did rake -T and run rake task than i got the mail.

Comment: set :output, '/log/cron_log.log'    set  this line to top of the your schedule.rb and check whats going on with whenever log.

Comment: i am not getting logs in cron_log.log file

Comment: are you using rvmrc file as well ??

Comment: did you check log file after restart your server?

Comment: yes  ruby-1.8.7-p374  Tushar Pal

Comment: no logs are generated.

Comment: i used  sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog here cron job working but i didn't get any mail

Comment: Try running `cd /home/rank/gvs/new_rank/vendor/plugins/rank_gvs_customization &&
   RAILS_ENV=development rake send_digest_email:send_digest_email` in console and post output here